# Saving Figure as High Resolution or Lossless Image that can be Zoomed in without Pixelation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a big plot in MATLAB (4095 points total) and I want to export this figure as a high res image which can be zoomed in just like the original figure can be zoomed in. Below I attached two images, one is full size plot and the second one was exported separately by zooming in the figure and then exporting. 1st image gets pixelated (obviously) when I zoom in. So my question is if it is possible to export the figure as an image (any format but .fig) that can be zoomed in for more granular detail.
[image: PNG Image]
[image: Zoomed]

Comment: Sure. Just use a vector format, such as `eps`or `pdf`

Comment: I would suggest using [this tool.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)

Comment: @LuisMendo Consider putting that into an answer. I'll up-vote it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save the figure using a [vector format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), such as `pdf`, `ps` or `eps`.

For example: try

```
plot(sin(0:.001:2*pi)) %// example graph
```

The resulting figure is:

[image]

Then print to `pdf`:

```
print -dpdf example %// Or change -dpdf to -deps, -depsc, -dps, -dpsc
```

Now open the generated file, `example.pdf`. You can zoom on it and you won't see it pixelated. Here's an example of the top of the sinusoid at 6400% zoom.

[image]

Comment: Let me check if it works for me, and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: You could also try `-deps`, `-depsc`, `-dps`, `-dpsc` in addition to `-dpdf`, I've included that in the answer

Comment: I've never used that format, but I see the "V" stands for "vector", so yes, it's also a vector graphics format